Scroll Not Working Properly In Angular Project
As you can see below, the overflow I use in my html code does not work properly on mobile devices. It does this problem only on mobile devices and does not cause problems on desktop devices
I would be grateful if you could help me
example video
Child Component;
 <ng-container>
        <div class="row scrollable-container">
            <div class="col-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{'measurmentPoint' | translate}}</th>
                            <th>{{'Value' | translate}}</th>

                            <th *ngFor="let realMeasurmentTableDetail of getSortedMeasurementDetails();let j = index">
                                <span style="text-wrap: nowrap;"> {{realMeasurmentTableDetail?.sizeName + ' -' + realMeasurmentTableDetail?.bPantNo}}</span>
                                <button class="btn btn-icon deleteBtn"
                                    (click)="deleteColumn(realMeasurmentTableDetail.pantNo,realMeasurmentTableDetail.sizeId)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                    
                        <tr cdkDrag cdkDragLockAxis="y" [ngClass]="{'selected-row': rowIndex === selectedRowIndex}"
                            *ngFor="let measurementPoint of checkedMeasurmentPointId;index as rowIndex">
                    
                            <td>
                                <div class="content-container">
                                    <div class="icon-handle" cdkDragHandle>
                                        <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                            <path
                                                d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z">
                                            </path>
                                            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        {{getMeasurementPoint(measurementPoint)}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                    
                            <td [ngClass]="{'selected-value': rowIndex === selectedRowIndex}">
                                {{getMeasurementTableValue(measurementPoint)}}
                            </td>
                    
                            <td id="value"
                                [ngClass]="{'selected-cell': selectedRowIndex === rowIndex && selectedColumnIndex === columnIndex}"
                                *ngFor="let currRealMeasurementTableDetail of getOrderedMeasurmentTableDetailById(measurementPoint);let columnIndex = index;"
                                (click)="setClickIndex(rowIndex,columnIndex)">
                                {{currRealMeasurementTableDetail.value}}
                            </td>
                    
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

Css Code;
.scrollable-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    zoom: 75%;
    touch-action: auto !important;

}
